# Error in Nested Reactive Forms - Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I followed a youtube video and followed axact code, but still getting the error.
I dont know if it is deprecated.
Saw some similar questions in stackoverflow, but my case is different.

I wrote the below line in template file and failed,

```html
 <div formArrayName = "brands" *ngFor="let brand of productsForm.controls.brands.controls; let i = index;">
```

then wrote a get function in ts file as below

```
  getControls() {
    return this.productsForm.controls.brands.controls
  }
```

again failed

ts file..

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormArray,
} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-add-courses',
  templateUrl: './admin-add-courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-add-courses.component.scss'],
})
export class AdminAddCoursesComponent implements OnInit {


  public videoCards: any[] = [];

  productsForm: FormGroup;

  products = [
    {
      'brand': "Apple"
    },
    {
      'brand': "Samsung"
    },
  ];

  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.createForm(this.products);
  }

  public createForm(products) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < products.lenght; i++) {
      arr.push(this.buildProduct(products[i]));
    }
    this.productsForm = this.fb.group({
      category: [''],
      brands: this.fb.array(arr)
    });
  }

  buildProduct(product): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      title: [product.brand],
      value: [''],
    });
  }

  showData() {
    console.log(this.productsForm.value);
  }

  getControls() {
    return this.productsForm.controls.brands.controls
  }

}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]= "productsForm" (submit)="showData()">
      <div>
        Category:
        <input type="text" formControlName="category">
      </div>
      <div formArrayName="brands" *ngFor="let brand of getControls(); let i = index;">
        <div formGroupName ="{{i}}">
          {{ brand.get('title').value}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a type conversion to FormArray as it's expecting that.

```
getControls() {
    return (this.productsForm.controls.brands as FormArray).controls;
}

<div formArrayName="brands" *ngFor="let brand of getControls(); let i = index;"></div>
```

Also don't forget to import FormAray from @angular/forms

Comment: I followed this, did not work, no errors but, nothing is being displayed.
this is my template 
```
<form [formGroup]= "productsForm" (submit)="showData()">
      <div>
        Category:
        <input type="text" formControlName="category">
      </div>
      <div formArrayName="brands" *ngFor="let brand of getControls(); let i = index;">
        <div formGroupName ="{{i}}">
          {{ brand.get('title').value}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Give me 5 mins I will check it for you

Comment: Looks like a small typo for (var i = 0; i < products.lenght; i++){} spelling of length is wrong. Let me know if still you're facing any issue.

Comment: Yes it was a typo.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Anytime buddy 

Answer (score 0):

Dayand, the **correct way** to access a control is using `get`

```html
    <div *ngFor="let brand of productsForm.get('brands').controls;let i=index">
    ..
    </div>
```

But you don't use directly in the .html because Angular don't know what kind of control is `productsForm.get('brands')` so generally you use a getter indicate Angular what kind of element should expect

```js
    get brandsArray()
    {
        return this.productForms.get('brands') as FormArray
    }
```

Now, you can use

```html
    <div *ngFor="let brand of brandsArray.controls;let i=index">
    ..
    </div>
```

NOTE: I don't know who was the first person that used form.controls.mycontrol to get the control, but it's a very, very bad idea. No body sure that this way works in a future